# Are we future gods?

Tags: gods, belief

I am talking about mainly two things religions gods and ancestors gods,

The people of past stories and volumes are our gods, and also many religions consider their ancestors as gods, they never considered themself as gods and we are considering them gods because we can't doing the right things and be honest like them,

I wonder if will we be gods for the future generation after about 50, 100, or 200 years?

Comment: Many Hindus keep dead anscestors photo in pooja room so your son or daughter may keep your photo in pooja room with a garland. God enough ig.

Comment: People are on up and down situations with karmphal, like remember the Indra & ants story ? Whoever was in Indra position did bad stuffs and then reborn as ant. So I think it can go up and down very unpredictably.